# How to use carrierwave cache on Heroku multiple dynos?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, carrierwave

I have an app with Carrierwave on Heroku. On a page, I have 2 forms: 1 ajax form for uploading a picture and 1 normal form for additional information needed to create the object. Suppose my Carrierwave mount is `:picture`, every time the ajax form is submitted, the picture is saved temporarily into the public folder and its path is returned as `:picture_cache`. The second form then uses that to know which picture to be created with the new object on the second request. This works fine for a single dyno.

Different dynos don't know about each other's filesystems. Thus if the request to submit the 2nd form doesn't hit the same dyno as the request of the first form, it can't find the image.

Has anyone tackled this problem?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Without having to use Mongoid?

Answer (score 2):

i use a custom model and store all files, including tmp ones, in mongodb.  the uploads are marked as tmp.  ones the models is 'saved' i simply remove the 'tmp' flag.  in this way all nodes see all images all the time.  it's pretty crazy that the carrierwave default is to cache in ./tmp since many multi-node configuration would see this issue (unless the balancer implements session affinity).

here is my model and controller, etc: https://gist.github.com/3161569

you have to do some custom work in the form:

- save every file posted, no matter what
- relay the posted file id in a hidden field
- on save look for a file and/or previously uploaded id
- make the model associations

this approach, although it isn't 'magic' also gives the following awesome side effects:

- you have *one* process running jobs in the background to thumbnail the images vs. spinning up image_magick whenever a user hits 'submit' (which is a *serious* DOS vector, esp on memory limited hosts like heroku)
- you can migrate images to s3 in the background, hourly, whatever, and the uploads simply have a new url (in this case the controller need to issue a permanant redirect if it notices this).  this is really nice because you can keep 'em in the db for dev, staging, etc.  and migrate some, or all, uploads onto s3 whenever without changing any upload or view code.

Comment: What about if you're not on Mongoid?

Comment: @marflar I'm sure most SQL databases too make it possible to store binary data like images e.g. if your working with PG [this SO-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744032/modeling-postgresqls-large-objects-in-rails#id=answer-14754647) and the [Large Object interface documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/lo-interfaces.html) might be of interest to you.