# Modeling PostgreSQL's large objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, blob

I need to save large objects in the db in my rails app. I think that I can have a table created in SQL as

```
CREATE TABLE files (
id serial NOT NULL,
name string NOT NULL,
blob_oid oid NUT NULL
)
```

And then store the data in Ruby as

```
conn.exec("BEGIN")
lo = conn.lo_import(data)
conn.exec("COMMIT")
file = File.new
file.name = file_name; file.blob_oid = lo.id
file.save
```

First of all, is this correct? Secondly, how do I describe the model for File in Rails. What is the data type of `Friend.blob_oid` in Rails? Can I create the files table using a migration in Rails?

Comment: Are you sure you need large objects? Most of the time using `bytea` to store "BLOB" data is the better fit.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I guess I could use bytea or text (I am storing text files), but wouldn't that load the whole file within an ActiveRecord object? I thought that could create memory problems. What's a good way to store such files in Rails with pg?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using ActiveRecord that comes with Rails with one of its adapters, the only formal mapping of database type to Rails or Ruby type that happens is typically defined in the `NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES` constant in the adapter which is returned via its `native_database_types` method. For PostgreSQL in Rails 3.2.x, that is in `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter` which is [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L220). So, for that adapter, the "binary" type in Rails maps to the "bytea" type in PG. For some types, you can override that database type that it maps to using a gem called [activerecord-native_db_types_override](https://github.com/garysweaver/activerecord-native_db_types_override). But, we want to use large objects, so...

**Migrations**

As Jim Deville noted in the comments, you can specify the custom typed column in the table like:

```
t.column :some_oid, 'blob_oid', :null => false
```

If you need to do even more that is non-standard, you can also use an `execute("SQL GOES HERE;")` to create the table using straight SQL. And, if you have an existing legacy schema or SQL changes that have been made outside of the migrations, consider using structure.sql (`config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` option in `config/application.rb` and then do: `rake db:structure:dump`).

**Large Objects Read/Write/Check Length/Delete**

Copied with some modifications to clarify, etc. from: https://github.com/diogob/carrierwave-postgresql/blob/v0.1.0/lib/carrierwave/storage/postgresql_lo.rb:

*Updated*: we can but don't need to put a begin before the lo_read/lo_write/lo_lseek and do lo_close in ensure block because per [PG documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/lo-interfaces.html#LO-CLOSE) "Any large object descriptors that remain open at the end of a transaction will be closed automatically." (thanks to Diogo for that info)

```
    require 'pg'

    ...

    def read
      (...).transaction do
        lo = connection.lo_open(identifier)
        content = connection.lo_read(lo, file_length)
        connection.lo_close(lo)
        content
      end
    end

    def write(file)
      (...).transaction do
        lo = connection.lo_open(identifier, ::PG::INV_WRITE)
        size = connection.lo_write(lo, file.read)
        connection.lo_close(lo)
        size
      end
    end

    def delete
      connection.lo_unlink(identifier)
    end

    def file_length
      (...).transaction do
        lo = connection.lo_open(identifier)
        size = connection.lo_lseek(lo, 0, 2)
        connection.lo_close(lo)
        size
      end
    end
```

Instead of `connection`, use the raw connection from the model or base, e.g. `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection` (see [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/AbstractAdapter/raw_connection)).

`(...).transaction` is calling transaction on model or base, e.g. `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` (see [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html)).

`identifier` is the oid that you either need to pass in/set or get from just doing a `connection.lo_creat`.

Other examples/info:

- http://rubydoc.info/github/nedforce/devcms-core/DbFile
- https://github.com/nedforce/devcms-core
- http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/ruby/9780596510329/database/largebinary_objects

The latter and some answers [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database) suggest that you might want to consider storage of large files separate from the DB, e.g. so that you can use cloud storage. But, if only store the paths/IDs to external files that are *not* managed by the DB, you lose ACID consistency (one or more DB records could point to one or more files that aren't there or one or more files could exist that don't have one or more associated records in the database). Another argument for storing files on the file system is that you can stream files, but PG large object stores files on the filesystem in a way managed by postgres to both ensure ACID consistency and allow streaming (which you can't do with a normal BLOB/Rails binary type). So, it just depends; some find storing in separate storage using path references a better option, and some prefer ACID consistency via Large Objects.

**The Easy Way**

Just use [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) and [carrierwave-postgresql](https://github.com/diogob/carrierwave-postgresql).

Comment: You can use normal migrations with non normal migration types: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#supported-types